# Python convert utf-8 back to string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a string which looks like

```
a = 'Verm\xc3\xb6gensverzeichnis'
```

When i do print(a), it shows me the right result, which is Vermögensverzeichnis.

```
print(a)
Vermögensverzeichnis
```

What i want to do is to calculate the occurrence of each letter using Counter() and save them in a dataframe. When I use Counter(a), it gives me a result like this:

```
 Counter({'V': 1,
         'c': 1,
         'e': 4,
         'g': 1,
         'h': 1,
         'i': 2,
         'm': 1,
         'n': 2,
         'r': 2,
         's': 2,
         'v': 1,
         'z': 1,
         '\xb6': 1,
         '\xc3': 1})
```

Could you please help me get rid of codes like \xc3\xb6? I have tried with many existing answers, unfortunately they do not work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I take it this is Python 2? Then just **print** `a.lower()`. You already have UTF-8 encoded data, the `\x...` escape sequences are only part of the **representation** of the string object. They make it easier for you to debug code with Python strings with non-ASCII values.

Comment: I'm not sure what `a.lower()` has got to do with this. Strings are immutable, so `a.lower()` returns a new string object. Perhaps you forgot to assign the output to another variable, or back to `a`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that i want to calculate the occurrence of each letter, not to print them and show the result. That is why i do need the right result from the program not the print function. Could you please help me?

Comment: Main question: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @ShaLi: then *decode* from UTF-8 bytes to a Unicode string, and count Unicode codepoints instead. (And [read up on Unicode versus bytes](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) so you understand why you want to do that).

Comment: @ShaLi: and yes, you'll then count `u'\xf6'` characters, but when you print `u'\xf6'` you'll see that that's the codepoint for `ö`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks a lot! I'll try with it

Answer (score 1):

This must be Python 2.  Work with Unicode if you want to count characters vs. encoded bytes.  `\xc3\xb6` are the encoded bytes of `ö`:

```
>>> a = 'Verm\xc3\xb6gensverzeichnis'
>>> print a # Note this only works if your terminal is configured for UTF-8 encoding.
Vermögensverzeichnis
```

Decode to Unicode.  It should still print correctly as long as your terminal is configured correctly:

```
>>> u = a.decode('utf8')
>>> u
u'Verm\xf6gensverzeichnis'
>>> print u
Vermögensverzeichnis
```

Count the Unicode code points:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(u)
Counter({u'e': 4, u'i': 2, u'n': 2, u's': 2, u'r': 2, u'c': 1, u'v': 1, u'g': 1, u'h': 1, u'V': 1, u'm': 1, u'\xf6': 1, u'z': 1})
```

`u'\xf6'` is the Unicode codepoint for `ö`.  Print the keys and values to display them on the terminal properly:

```
>>> for k,v in Counter(u).iteritems():
...     print k,v
...     
c 1
v 1
e 4
g 1
i 2
h 1
V 1
m 1
n 2
s 2
r 2
ö 1
z 1
```

Future study to see where this will break: *Unicode normalization* and *graphemes*.